# Typescript sometimes doesn't accept props passed by Redux container

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I have one Redux container component, `HomeContainer`, which `connect`s the `Home` component. When I use the `HomeContainer` component in my `App`, Typescript is happy, because it knows that `HomeContainer` provides all the props that `Home` needs, and therefore doesn't need any props of its own.

#### `Home`

```js
type HomeProps = {
  cuvettes: number | null,
  pipettes: number | null,
  fetchConfigState: Function,
  setConfigState: Function
}

const Home = ({ cuvettes, pipettes, fetchConfigState, setConfigState }: HomeProps) => {
  
  // ...the rest of the component...

  return (
    <Box>

      {/* ...other stuff ... */}
      
      <StartStopContainer/>
      
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Home
```

#### `HomeContainer`

```js
const mapState = ({ data }: RootState) => ({
  cuvettes: data.cuvettesCount,
  pipettes: data.pipettesCount
})

const mapDispatch = ({ fetchConfigState, setConfigState });

const HomeContainer = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Home)

export default HomeContainer;
```

#### `App`

```js
const App = () => {
  // ...other stuff...  
  return <HomeContainer/>
}
```

However, typescript reports an error on the call to `StartStopContainer` in the `Home` component above, saying that I need to give it the props that `StartStop` needs. But `StartStopContainer` is providing them from `connect`, just like `HomeContainer` is! Why is one working but not the other?

#### `StartStop`

```js
type StartStopProps = {
  requestRobotStart: Function,
  requestRobotStop: Function,
  robotMode: RobotMode
}

const StartStop = ({ requestRobotStart, requestRobotStop, robotMode }: StartStopProps) => {
  
  const start: MouseEventHandler = async () => await requestRobotStart()
  const stop: MouseEventHandler = async () => await requestRobotStop()
  
  return (
    <Box>
      <Button onClick={ start } variant='contained'>START</Button>
      <Button onClick={ stop } variant='contained'>STOP</Button>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default StartStop;
```

#### `StartStopContainer`

```js
const mapState = ({ data }: RootState) => ({
  robotMode: data.robotMode
})

const mapDispatch = ({ fetchConfigState, setConfigState });

const StartStopContainer = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(StartStop)

export default StartStopContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake.
On StartStopContainer,

```
const mapDispatch = ({ fetchConfigState, setConfigState });
```

This should be like this.

```
const mapDispatch = ({ requestRobotStart, requestRobotStop });
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I knew it would be something stupid like that. I kept looking between the files and seeing that the structure was the same, but I was missing the trees for the forest!